# Biblatex and Chicago - leading space before location in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I'm having a problem eliminating a leading space which has appeared between the opening bracket and the location of a publisher in Chicago style footnote references created with Biblatex.

For example: ( Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 1998) where it should be (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 1998).

The problem appeared after upgrading to biblatex-chicago 0.9.7a, biblatex 1.4 and BibDesk 1.5.4 and also occurs when I recompile older source files which formatted the references correctly.

I notice the field 'Address' in BibDesk is now called 'Location' - but I can't see anything about this change in the BibDesk documentation, and it anyway doesn't seem likely that this would cause the problem.

Grateful for any suggestions - I've not been able to find any solutions here or elsewhere.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Sure: with `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` in the preamble this `\footcite[][13]{Biardeau:1995pr}` produces Madeleine Biardeau, Hinduism: The Anthropology of a Civilization ( Delhi: Oxford University Press, 1995), 13. where it should produce Madeleine Biardeau, Hinduism: The Anthropology of a Civilization (Delhi: Oxford University Press, 1995), 13.  The same code had previously worked correctly.

Comment: I think this is fixed in biblatex 1.4a which was a release a couple of days ago.

Comment: @PLK Thanks - I've updated to biblatex 1.4a - the space has gone, but only to be replaced by a zero. Anyway, good to know someone's onto it, guess I'll watch for updates.

Comment: I'm also seeing the leading zero. Thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: Now resolved (biblatex 1.4b)

Comment: @PLK: Could you please post this as an answer. Then the question will be removed from the “Unanswered” list.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been resolved in biblatex v1.4b.